# looping through objects within an object with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, assign

The script below currently outputs:

```
{
    "title1": {
        "0": "undefined"
    },
    "title2": "&amp; three",
    "title3": "&amp; four"
}
```

The desired output being:

```
 {
      "title1": {
        "nested1": "one",
        "nested2": "&amp; two"
      },
      "title2": "&amp; three ",
      "title3": "&amp; four"
    }
```

My question is what is required in the if statement to successfully loop through the properties of the [key][innerKey] and pass them through the encode function and return them to 'out'?

I have been trying to solve it using a for loop within the first part of the if statement without success. I figure it needs to follow a logic along the lines of:

- if arr[key] is an object then
- output the [key]:
- then loop through all properties of the [key]
- and pass them through the function encode
- and return them to 'out'

thanks.

```
var arr = {
  "title1": {
    "nested1": "one",
    "nested2": "& two"
  },
  "title2": "& three ",
  "title3": "& four"
};

var encodedValues = Object.keys(arr).reduce(function(out,key,innerKey) {

  if (typeof arr[key] == "object") {
     return Object.assign(out, {[key]: {[innerKey]: encode(arr[key][innerKey])}})

  } else {
     return Object.assign(out, {[key]: encode(arr[key])})
  }

}, {});

console.log(encodedValues)
```

Comment: Can you please post the expected output? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Yes Sure. Sorry for the lack of clarity. Just updated the original post.

Comment: Is the depth of the object always going to be == 1?

Comment: yes I think so if I understand what you mean - i.e. there would be no deeper level of nested objects than the example given. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? (recursion)

```
var arr = {
  "title1": {
    "nested1": "one",
    "nested2": "& two"
  },
  "title2": "& three ",
  "title3": "& four"
};

var encode = function(val){ return encodeURI(val) };

var encodeValues = function(arr){
  var obj = {};
    for(var key in arr){
    if(typeof arr[key] == "object"){
      obj[key] = encodeValues(arr[key]);
    }else{
      obj[key] = encode(arr[key]);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

var encodedValues = encodeValues(arr);

console.log(encodedValues);
```

Comment: Thankyou. This worked perfect when I tested. So would this be a recursive function as you reference encodeValues within the function and it loops back on itself?

Comment: Exactly. I jump at the chance to use recursion :p

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this should work:

```
function encodeValues(arr) {
  Object.keys(arr).forEach(item => {
    if (typeof arr[item] === "object") encodeValues(arr[item]);
    else arr[item] = encode(arr[item]);
  });
  return arr;
}

var encodedValues = encodeValues(arr);
```

Same code in ES5:

```
function encodeValues(arr) {
  var keys = Object.keys(arr);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[keys[i]] === "object") encodeValues(arr[keys[i]]);
    else arr[keys[i]] = encode(arr[keys[i]]);
  }
 return arr;
}

var encodedValues = encodeValues(arr);
```

This can work for every depth you have (objects nested in other objects)

Comment: Thanks very much. Oddly I just gave it a go implementing both the above and  console.log(encodedValues); is returning undefined. will double check.

Comment: @fivedoor ups, sorry, I didn't test the ES5 version and I did a mistake writing the for, now it should work!

Comment: ah yes sorry I just pounced on Pat’s solution meantime - that’s working great too now.  Thanks for your help!